# Beautiful Soup - taking classes out of an HTML file

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an HTML file and I want to take grab the text from this block, shown here:

```
 <strong class="fullname js-action-profile-name">User Name</strong>
    <span>&rlm;</span>
    <span class="username js-action-profile-name"><s>@</s><b>UserName</b></span>
```

I want it to display as:

```
User Name
@UserName
```

How would I do this using Beautiful Soup?

Answer (score 1):

Use the "text" attribute. Example:

```
>>> b = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup(open('/tmp/x.html'), convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulStoneSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

>>> print b.find(attrs={"id": "container"}).text
User Name‏@UserName
```

In x.html I have a div containing the html you provided, with an id of "container". Note that I convert the ‏ to \u200f with BeautifulStoneSoup. To insert a newline (that wouldn't be introduced by a browser) just replace u'\u200f' with '\n'.

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<strong class="fullname js-action-profile-name">User Name</strong>
    <span>&rlm;</span>
    <span class="username js-action-profile-name"><s>@</s><b>UserName</b></span>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

username = soup.find(attrs={'class':'username js-action-profile-name'}).text
fullname = soup.find(attrs={'class':'fullname js-action-profile-name'}).text

print fullname
print username
```

Outputs:

```
User Name
@UserName
```

Two notes:

1. Use `bs4` if you're starting something new / just learning BS.
2. You will probably be loading your HTML from an external file, so replace `html` with a file object.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes *index.html* contains the markup from the question:

```
import BeautifulSoup

def displayUserInfo():

    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(open("index.html"))
    fullname_ele = soup.find(attrs={"class": "fullname js-action-profile-name"})
    fullname = fullname_ele.contents[0]
    print fullname

    username_ele = soup.find(attrs={"class": "username js-action-profile-name"})
    username = ""
    for child in username_ele.findChildren():
        username += child.contents[0]
    print username

if __name__ == '__main__':
    displayUserInfo()

# prints:
# User Name
# @UserName
```